# Is Java Native Interface(JNI) an example for Adapter pattern?

Tags: java, design-patterns

I used JNI in my project to call C++ library and it looks like adapter design pattern. 
 Need to confirm whether JNI is an example for Adapter pattern or not.

Comment: This is more of a phylosophical question. It depends on how broadly you take the definition of *Adapter*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it isn't. A JNI is just a set of plain functions; their names being the result of the interplay between the `native` keyword in Java and the generator `javah`.

The adapter pattern is concerned with the interaction of two interfaces.